# Gnome make mouse keys config persistent

Tags: gnome, xkb, profile

I enabled mouse keys in gnome settings and the default mouse pointer was unusable due to its slowness, so I searched and found this command that fixes the problem:

```
xkbset ma 60 10 10 5 2
```

The problem now is that I have to run this command every time I login to my computer, and I can't find a way to make it persistent.

I tried to add the command to `~/.profile` but it didn't work.

*I'm on Ubuntu 18*